# Cannot execute Nhibernate query

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I get the following Nhiberante error, but have no idea why:

> could not execute query [ select attachment0_.AttachmentId as
>   Attachme1_9_, attachment0_.Name as Name9_, attachment0_.IconUrl as
>   IconUrl9_, attachment0_.UserId as UserId9_,
>   attachment0_.AttachmentTypeId as Attachme6_9_, attachment0_.IsDeleted
>   as IsDeleted9_, attachment0_.ArrivalTime as ArrivalT8_9_,
>   attachment0_.LocationId as LocationId9_ from Attachment_Attachment
>   attachment0_ where attachment0_.DYNAMIC_TYPE='Attachment' and 1=0 ]
>   [SQL: select attachment0_.AttachmentId as Attachme1_9_,
>   attachment0_.Name as Name9_, attachment0_.IconUrl as IconUrl9_,
>   attachment0_.UserId as UserId9_, attachment0_.AttachmentTypeId as
>   Attachme6_9_, attachment0_.IsDeleted as IsDeleted9_,
>   attachment0_.ArrivalTime as ArrivalT8_9_, attachment0_.LocationId as
>   LocationId9_ from Attachment_Attachment attachment0_ where
>   attachment0_.DYNAMIC_TYPE='Attachment' and 1=0]

Update:

inner exception:

```
Failed to convert parameter value from a WhereSelectListIterator`2 to a Guid.
```

My query:

```
x => locationsIds.Contains(x.LocationId)
```

Comment: Check the InnerException

Comment: This is not enough info to go, please provide more...

Comment: Failed to convert parameter value from a WhereSelectListIterator`2 to a Guid.

Comment: What type is locationsIds? Also, I'm sure not nHibernate can handle this type of query, essentially a WHERE [field] in [LIST] where list is a variable.

Comment: @ Rich ids are guid. How can I verify what is applicable linq by NH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `InnerException`. I'm sure it will point you to the correct place.

Comment: Failed to convert parameter value from a WhereSelectListIterator`2 to a Guid. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

`locationsIds` is probably an IEnumerable returned by a call to `Where`. The simplest solution is to explicitly convert it to a list:

```
var idsList = locationIds.ToList();
x => idsList.Contains(x.LocationId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this specific question have been answered here, but I have also had this exception (with different column names) and the reason it failed was that I had used the wrong database.  I had added a new table to one database, but when I ran the code I had configured it to use another database.  Once I used the correct database the error disappeared.

I hope this helps someone!